# playframework connection closed while using both slick and anorm

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, anorm

I have a project use both slick and anorm.

```
I define a method for slick 

  object DBCache {
    def apply(app: play.api.Application) = Cache.getOrElse[Database](app.hashCode.toString){
      Database.forDataSource(PlayDB.getDataSource("default")(app))
    }
  }

  private[persist] def inSession[T](block: Session => T) = DBCache(current).withSession(block(_))
```

And when I can a batch insert method use anorm

```
def batchInsert(customerAccounts: Seq[Customer]) = DB.withConnection { implicit conn =>
      val sql = SQL(insertSql)
      val batch = customerAccounts.foldLeft(sql.asBatch) {
        (sql, c) => sql.addbatch(xxx)
      }
}
```

It reports

> play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.]

How to avoid this error

Comment: Do you have this every time or sporadicly?

Comment: @Somatik periodically, not every time

Comment: lots of problems on the bonecp issue tracker related to these https://bugs.launchpad.net/bonecp/+bug/1243551 https://bugs.launchpad.net/bonecp/+bug/1258339 an option is to try a different connection pool plugin (c3p0)

Comment: there is a pull request https://github.com/wwadge/bonecp/pull/20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the master branch of playframework disable the tracking , 

`datasource.setDisableConnectionTracking(
conf.getBoolean("disableConnectionTracking").getOrElse(true))`

So I disable it in `Global.scala`.

There'are still some problem. When sql error happends, connection may be closed. Then I turned to use alibaba's data source https://github.com/alibaba/druid. It works fine!

Comment: I turned to `druid` data source used in alibaba. It works fine!